# Trouble with DecimalType converting an array of attribute name and DataType to an array of StructField in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I would like to map an array containing different DataTypes to automatically create StructField. But I have some problems with DecimalType. For example, if I test

```
val myType1 = StringType
val testString =  myType1.asInstanceOf[DataType]
```

I have no problem. But with the line below

```
val myType2 = DecimalType
val testDecimal =  myType2.asInstanceOf[DataType]
```

I get this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.spark.sql.types.DecimalType$ cannot be cast to org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataType
```

I don't understand because in the documentation I thought that DecimalType inherits DataType:

https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/types/DecimalType.html.

So I'm looking for a parent object of all "spark.sql.type".

My goal is to map something like that:

```
Array(("name",StringType),("size", LongType),("att3",DecimalType),("age",IntegerType))
```

to an array of StructField.

Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: Why are you casting them back to `DataType`?

Comment: Because it is contained into row not like my exemple. So I get the name of the attribute calling myrow(0).asInstance[String] and the type of the attribute calling myrow(1).asInstance[DataType]. And i get the error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use only `DecimalType`, you get a reference to an object of `DecimalType` and not the exact object.

```
val a = DecimalType
a: org.apache.spark.sql.types.DecimalType.type = org.apache.spark.sql.types.DecimalType$@156bb545
```

Instead of,

```
val a = DecimalType(10,0)
a: org.apache.spark.sql.types.DecimalType = DecimalType(10,0)
```

Alternatives would be to use :

```
myType2(10,0).asInstanceOf[DataType]
org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataType = DecimalType(10,0)

//or if you want max precision and scala

myType2.Unlimited.asInstanceOf[DataType]
org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataType = DecimalType(38,18)
```